# Unification in pattern matching case

Tags: pattern-matching, coq, dependent-type, unification, reflect

I was trying to write a function whose type is `forall n, option (n = 1)`.

I choose `option` as an altertnative to `reflect` avoiding giving the proof of the negative case. So `Some` plays the role `ReflectT` and holds the proof, while `None` doesn't hold the negative proof.

```
Definition is_1 n: bool:=
  match n with
    1 => true |
    _ => false
  end.

Lemma is_1_complete : forall n, is_1 n = true -> n = 1.
intros.
destruct n. simpl in H. discriminate.
destruct n. reflexivity.
simpl in H. discriminate.
Qed.

Lemma a_nat_is_1_or_not: forall n, option (n = 1).
intros.
cut (is_1 n = true -> n = 1).
- 
intros.
destruct n. exact None.
destruct n. simpl in H. exact (Some (H (eq_refl))).
exact None.
-
exact (is_1_complete n).
Qed.
```

I've done with tactics. `a_nat_is_1_or_not` is the proof. And I thought I can do this writing the definition directly, so I tried.

```
Definition a_nat_is_1_or_not' n: option (n = 1) :=
  match is_1 n with
     true => Some (is_1_complete n eq_refl)
     | false => None
  end.
```

But Coq saids

```
Error:
In environment
n : nat
The term "eq_refl" has type "is_1 n = is_1 n"
while it is expected to have type "is_1 n = true" (cannot unify "is_1 n" and
"true").
```

It seems `is_1 n` cannot be unified to `true` in `true` case of the pattern matching of itself.

So I tried a more trivial example.

```
Definition every_true_is_I x: x = I :=
  match x with
     I => eq_refl
  end.
```

It works.

What is the difference between `a_nat_is_1_or_not'` and `every_truer_is_I`?
Am I missing something? What can I do for writing a valid definition of `forall n, is_1 n = true -> n = 1.`?

Comment: As @Guillaume said your problem is that you're losing information, alternatively you can solve with Ltac you just have to use the remember tactic which makes the same thing.  Definition a_nat_is_1_or_not' n : option (n = 1). remember (is_1n). destruct b. exact (Some (@is_1_complete n (eq_sym Heqb))). exact None. Defined.

Comment: If you don't need the negative case, you could consider the sigma type use.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The difference is that, in `a_nat_is_1_or_not'`, you are depending on an external term whose type is `is_1 n = true -> _`. If you want `a_nat_is_1_or_not'` to look like `every_true_is_I`, you have to make sure that all the occurrences of `is_1 n` are covered by the pattern matching:

```
Definition a_nat_is_1_or_not' n: option (n = 1) :=
  match is_1 n as b return ((b = true -> _) -> _) with
  | true => fun H => Some (H eq_refl)
  | false => fun _ => None
  end (is_1_complete n).
```

Notice how `is_1_complete` has been instantiated outside the pattern matching, so that its occurrence of `is_1 n` (renamed `b`) is handled.

There is another way to do it, perhaps a bit more idiomatic. Instead of generalizing the whole context, you just keep enough information to fill all the holes:

```
Definition a_nat_is_1_or_not' n: option (n = 1) :=
  match is_1 n as b return (is_1 n = b -> _) with
  | true => fun H => Some (is_1_complete n H)
  | false => fun _ => None
  end eq_refl.
```

But the idea is the same. By instantiating `eq_refl` outside the pattern matching, you do not lose any information when matching on `is_1 n`.